# Best Practice: Defining a large database using SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper, in which I have defined my database tables and columns to be created. These are strings like the one shown below:

```
public String AS_COLUMN_A_BTN5 = "a_btn5";
```

I have then defined a string for each CREATE TABLE statement. These tables are created in the onCreate() method.

The problem is that I have over 50 columns, so the file is getting really long and unmanageable.

What is the best practice for defining a large number of columns?

Comment: If you're using so many columns that the file is getting unmanageable, you should perhaps reconsider your database design.

Answer (score 0):

1. write your create-database.sql script in a file and save it to your /assets folder.
2. use the following in you `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

`onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase db )
{
    InputStream in_stream = null;
    try {
        in_stream = mContext.getResources().getAssets().open( CREATE_SCRIPT );
        String[] statements = parseSqlFile( in_stream );
        for ( String statement : statements ) {
            db.execSQL( statement );
        }
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if ( in_stream != null ) {
                in_stream.close();
            }
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
        }
    }
}
```

on line 8 you will find a method called `parseSqlFile()`. This is a method that takes a SQL script and splits it into sql statements. You can download it from [here](https://gist.github.com/kdehairy/5339450) (I used it from a blog I read long ago. unfortunately, I don't remember any more).

This way you can make use of your editor's syntax highlighting to spot typos in your sql script.

let me know if you had a problem.